# How do I remove the 'Continue Reading' tag from pages on my blogspot blog?

Tags: blog, blogger, tags

[My blog](http://www.krishnavatar.com) has pages at the navigation bar.   The 'Home' and 'About Me' pages show the 'Continue Reading' tag which I want to get rid of. I have used some extensions to add 'Continue Reading' functionality to my blog posts, but I don't want the tag. Any solutions?

Comment: What do you man by " i have borrowed some coding for the 'Continue Reading' option to my blog"?

Comment: I'm presuming that he means something like this: http://www.eblogtemplates.com/how-to-add-the-blogger-read-more-expandable-posts-link/ Correct me if I'm wrong about that though

Answer (score 2):

Also, you could take a peek at the template file for the different pages. Depending on how your site is set up, there's likely a code/comment that calls for the "Continue Reading" tag. In WordPress for example, by default the  quicktag is what you'd be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should constrain the 'continue reading' code to show up only on posts, not on pages.